# How to exclude value that is equal to zero while using Django aggregate queries for average or minimum

Tags: python, django, database, django-orm

I have a database table where some of the values in a column for sales are zero.

So far my query returns the min of all the values.

`Sale.objects.all().aggregate(minimum=Min('sale'))`

I want to exclude the values that are equal to zero while calculating the minimum or the average.

So my question is how is that query done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Sale.objects.filter(sales > 0).aggregate(minimum=Min('sale'))
```

or:

```
Sale.objects.exclude(sales = 0).aggregate(minimum=Min('sale'))
```